How can I upload an image to the ImageBB API in Android?
I want to utilize https://api.imgbb.com/1/upload in order to upload Bitmaps onto ImageBB using HttpURLConnection as follows:
Upload an image:
  public JsonObject uploadImage(Bitmap bitmap) throws IOException, ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
    JsonObject JSONInput = new JsonObject();
    JSONInput.addProperty(
      "image", BASE_64_IMAGE_STRING
    );
    JsonObject response = new Requests().execute(JSONInput).get();
    return response;
  }

Requests Class:
public class Requests extends AsyncTask<JsonObject, JsonObject, JsonObject> {
  @Override
  protected JsonObject doInBackground(JsonObject... jsonObjects) {
    URL url = null;
    url = new URL("https://api.imgbb.com/1/upload?key=API_KEY&expiration=300");
    HttpURLConnection connection = null;
    
    connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    
    connection.setRequestMethod("POST")
    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
    connection.setDoOutput(true);

    OutputStream os = connection.getOutputStream()
      OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(os, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
      osw.write(jsonObjects[0].toString());
      osw.flush();
      osw.close();

    connection.connect()
    String result = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getErrorStream()))
      .lines().collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));
    StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
      new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
      String responseLine = null;
      while ((responseLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
        response.append(responseLine.trim());
     

    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
    JsonElement jelem = gson.fromJson(response.toString(), JsonElement.class);
    return jelem.getAsJsonObject();
  }

  @Override
  protected void onPostExecute(JsonObject jsonObject) {
    super.onPostExecute(jsonObject);
  }
}

The jsonObjects consists of a single element which is of the form {"image": base64_representation_of_image"}
However, I keep getting {"status_code":400,"error":{"message":"Empty upload source.","code":130},"status_txt":"Bad Request"} back from the API. I can't seem to figure out what I am doing wrong.
I can't find out any resources which use similar APIs in Android. Any direction would be appreciated.
I am trying to use the HttpURLConnection class in order to make API requests to ImageBB. However, it does not seem to recognise the base64 image string I am passing

The ImgBB API is not expecting the data being send as a JSON body. Instead the content should be send either with GET variables or with POST form field data. This means that you cannot use the content type application/json to send your data to the API as a JSON string.
You have to send a "normal" HTTP POST request with form field data, with the required fields image and key. Check other questions like Sending HTTP POST Request In Java how to send a HTTP POST request with form field data with java.

If you could provide an example for how to do it using HttpURLConnection, that would be very helpful. The best I could find on that is this. Please note that I cant add the image parameter in the url since the base64 representations get very long

@Spongerooski Check other questions like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34915556/post-a-file-with-other-form-data-using-httpurlconnection
