# Sending emojis using POST with HttpURLConnection wrong encoding

Tags: android, unicode, httpurlconnection

I need to send File and POST params to php.  I found and copied code from [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26145565/4387074) to send POST request with file and params, and it work success. But when I try to POST text with emoji then server return me bad emoji text.
Example with **request** data, and **response**: 
[image]
First I thought that my php configured incorrect, but I tested this request with REST utility and server returned the correct response with emojis.
This is simple php code for test:

```
$data = $_POST('data');
echo $data;
```

What did I miss? Maybe I need to set charset in android request? but where I need to place it? Or maybe something wrong with code in solution source?

Answer (score 0):

I found another solution, work fine!

```
            final File uploadFile = new File(file);
            try {
                final MultipartUtility http = new MultipartUtility(new URL(url));
                http.addFormField("someField", "someValue");
                http.addFormField("data", data);
                http.addFilePart("someFile", uploadFile);
                String s =  http.finish();
                Log.d("response", s);
                return;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

public class MultipartUtility {
    private static final String CRLF = "\r\n";
    private static final String CHARSET = "UTF-8";

private static final int CONNECT_TIMEOUT = 15000;
private static final int READ_TIMEOUT = 10000;

private final HttpURLConnection connection;
private final OutputStream outputStream;
private final PrintWriter writer;
private final String boundary;

private final URL url;

public MultipartUtility(final URL url) throws IOException {
    this.url = url;

    boundary = "---------------------------" + System.currentTimeMillis();

    connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    connection.setConnectTimeout(CONNECT_TIMEOUT);
    connection.setReadTimeout(READ_TIMEOUT);
    connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
    connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", CHARSET);
    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
            "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary);
    connection.setUseCaches(false);
    connection.setDoInput(true);
    connection.setDoOutput(true);

    outputStream = connection.getOutputStream();
    writer = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, CHARSET),
            true);
}

public void addFormField(final String name, final String value) {
    writer.append("--").append(boundary).append(CRLF)
            .append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"").append(name)
            .append("\"").append(CRLF)
            .append("Content-Type: text/plain; charset=").append(CHARSET)
            .append(CRLF).append(CRLF).append(value).append(CRLF);
}

public void addFilePart(final String fieldName, final File uploadFile)
        throws IOException {
    final String fileName = uploadFile.getName();
    writer.append("--").append(boundary).append(CRLF)
            .append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"")
            .append(fieldName).append("\"; filename=\"").append(fileName)
            .append("\"").append(CRLF).append("Content-Type: ")
            .append(URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromName(fileName)).append(CRLF)
            .append("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary").append(CRLF)
            .append(CRLF);

    writer.flush();
    outputStream.flush();
    try  {
        final FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(uploadFile);
        final byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
        int bytesRead;
        while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }
        outputStream.flush();
    }finally {

    }

    writer.append(CRLF);
}

public void addHeaderField(String name, String value) {
    writer.append(name).append(": ").append(value).append(CRLF);
}

public String finish() throws IOException {
    writer.append(CRLF).append("--").append(boundary).append("--")
            .append(CRLF);
    writer.close();

    final int status = connection.getResponseCode();
    if (status != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
        throw new IOException(String.format("{0} failed with HTTP status: {1}",
                url, status));
    }

    try  {
        final InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();

        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(isr);
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
        String inputLine = in.readLine();
        while (inputLine != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);
            inputLine = in.readLine();
            if (inputLine != null)
                response.append('\r');
        }
        in.close();
        isr.close();
        return response.toString();

        /*
        final ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        final byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
        int bytesRead;
        while ((bytesRead = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            bytes.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }
        return bytes.toByteArray();
        */
    } finally {
        connection.disconnect();
    }
}
}
```