# Upload image to Laravel based server using API's post method

Tags: json, laravel, image, api, laravel-5

I am building a Laravel-based web API. In the project, we want to upload image using post method to the API server directly via an Android/iOS app. How can we do it?

Answer (score 0):

The server will take a POST request from clients with media file properly if you are posting a file with `Content-Type` as `multipart/form-data`.

See [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/requests#files) on how you can accept/save files in laravel.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19026256/how-to-upload-multipart-form-data-and-image-to-server-in-android) thread to see how you can post a `multipart/form-data` POST in android for reference.